# Why Range header returns me whole file?

Tags: java, http-headers, range, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get a part of a file from byte 0 to byte 0 with the following code. When I test this code on a file inside my local server (wampserver) and I print the size of this part, it will return me the size 1. But when I test this code on some files on the internet and I print the size of this part, it will return me the size of whole file!

Why is this happened? What is the reason of that?

My code is like this:

```
URL url = new URL("my link");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + 0 + "-" + 0);
connection.connect();
Log.i("Test" , "size: " + connection.getContentLength());
```

Comment: That is because not all servers respect the `HTTP` protocol specification. To achieve what you want you can simply get the connection's input stream and read from it only as many bytes as you need.

Comment: If you don't need that one byte and are just checking existence of the file, you an do an http HEAD, as opposed to an http GET.

Comment: @Titus But when i request different ranges like 1200-2000 , it returns me correct size and result!!!

Comment: @older coder but i only need that one byte For some reasons.

Comment: `InputStream is = new URL("my link").openStream(); byte first = (byte) is.read(); is.close();` Will get you the first `byte`.

Comment: Also, you can verify if a server accepts ranges requests by sending a `HEAD` request and checking the response for a `Accept-Ranges` header.